# Ядро и модули linux

Tags: linux

В какую сторону копать:
Как, используя echo, можно в одну команду заблокировать загрузку модуля cfb?

Comment: Видимо надо что-то записать в какой-то из файлов дерева `/sys`

Comment: @avp скорее блэклист в  /etc/modprobe.d/

Comment: Да, в конец файла блэклиста для модулей, когда требуется, чтобы они не загружались, добавить blacklist имя_модуля. Он расположен по абсолютному пути /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Answer (score 3):

Решение:
Существует специальный файл блэклиста для модулей, когда требуется, чтобы они не загружались. Он расположен по абсолютному пути /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. Для того, чтобы модуль добавился в блэклист, надо в конец файла добавить blacklist имя_модуля:

```
echo "blacklist cfb" >> /etc/modprobe.d/cfb-blacklist.conf
```

Comment: любой `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf`, не обязательно с именем blacklist.conf. `man 5 modprobe.d`